# тянущийся правый float:left уходит вниз

Tags: html, css

Господа помогите решить задачу:

картинка слева фиксированная, справа блок с текстом тянется и **не должен перескакивать вниз** при уменьшении размера окна браузера

что я только не пробовал - все равно скачет вниз. Как выйти из ситуации?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hibinyru/52t6r1ne/15/)

```css
.parrent {
  overflow: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.acount-box-avatar {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
}

.acount-box-right {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parrent">

  <div class="acount-box-avatar" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
    <img src="https://www.hibiny.com/images/2020/users/avatar100.jpg" width="80" height="80">
  </div>

  <div class="acount-box-right" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
    Тектст текст тексте текст Тектст текст тексте текст Тектст текст тексте текст
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если именно с `float`, то нужно задать ширину блокам, которая в сумме будет равна 100% (и с учетом отступов):

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.parrent {
  overflow: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.acount-box-avatar {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 16px;
  
  width: calc(25%  - 16px);
}

.acount-box-avatar img {width: 100%; height: auto; }

.acount-box-right {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parrent">

  <div class="acount-box-avatar" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
    <img src="https://www.hibiny.com/images/2020/users/avatar100.jpg" width="80" height="80">
  </div>

  <div class="acount-box-right" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
    Тектст текст тексте текст Тектст текст тексте текст Тектст текст тексте текст
  </div>
</div>
```

Но лучше использовать `flex`:

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.parrent {
  overflow: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
}

.acount-box-avatar {
  margin-right: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parrent">

  <div class="acount-box-avatar" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
    <img src="https://www.hibiny.com/images/2020/users/avatar100.jpg" width="80" height="80">
  </div>

  <div class="acount-box-right" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
    Тектст текст тексте текст Тектст текст тексте текст Тектст текст тексте текст
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! flex не хотелось бы.  в первом примере  если узкое разрешение (мобильник ) - фигня получается

Comment: аа, не заметил  .acount-box-avatar img {width: 100%; height: auto; } .... уже ближе :)

Comment: @hibinyru, для мобильных используйте медиа запросы и в них убирайте float. Например: ```@media (max-width: 767.98px) { .acount-box-avatar, acount-box-right { float: none; margin-right: 0; width: 100%; }```

Answer (score 1):

Просто уберите `display: block` из втоорго блока. И `float: left` там не нужен. https://jsfiddle.net/h5e7tmqw/

```css
.parrent {
  overflow: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.acount-box-avatar {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
}

.acount-box-right {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="parrent">

  <div class="acount-box-avatar" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
    <img src="https://www.hibiny.com/images/2020/users/avatar100.jpg" width="80" height="80">
  </div>

  <div class="acount-box-right" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
    Тектст текст тексте текст Тектст текст тексте текст Тектст текст тексте текст
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: тогда будет обтекание - мне это не нужно, но все равно спасибо :)

Comment: c `float: left` будет обтекание. Это же для этого обтекания `float` и создавался

Comment: ну я имел ввиду обтекание картинки получится, т.е. текст после картинки выйдет на ширину  100% , а мне это не нужно

Comment: Вы вроде справились с задачей. А так как вариант, увеличить левому блоку высоту до максимальной высоты правого блока.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо @HamSter , навел на мысль, помогло левому блоку задать width: 100px;

а правому width: calc(100% - 116px);

(пробовал так, но забыл про margin-right: 16)

Благодарю!